# how do I sort items with tinysortjs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this plugin: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/#customsortfunction

I have a select box with 3 options. When I select one of the options I want to list to sort by what is chosen...
Ex:

```
<select id="sort-news">
  <option value="cars">cars</option>
  <option value="house">house</option>
  <option value="birds">birds</option>
</select>
```

A news item will look like this:

```
<article data-category="house" class="news-item">
  <div class="thumb">
    <img alt="" title="" src="images/news-image.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="news-txt">
    <h3>Ny webportal</h3>
    <p>14:00 Først mountainbiker ved Moesgård Museum</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Lets assume there is a lot of news items, with different data-categories
Ex I have 10 news items, where the `data-category=""` is one of the 3 options I the select. 
When I choose something in the select I want the list to be sorted, with only the selected

If I click house in the select, I only want to display the news items with the `data-category="house"`

Is that possible with this plugin?

Comment: Are you talking about [this TinySort plugin](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/)? You should specify exactly what plugin, preferably with a link.

Comment: Yeah, thats the one :)

Comment: "If I click house in the select, I only want to display the news items with the data-category='house'" - that doesn't sound like a sort, that sounds like a filter. If you're saying that choosing "house" within your <select id="sort-news"> should then hide all news items with a data-category of "cars" or "birds", that's not what TinySort is designed to do. That being said, some simple jQ could be added to hide non-matching items when sorting; then again, if you're filtering out non-matching items, what are you leaving to sort on...? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

While the title of the post refers to sorting, the details of the post end with the requirement "If I click house in the select, **I only want to display** the news items with the `data-category="house"`"

This sounds like filtering, not sorting; to do so, since we know you're using jQuery, you can attach a .change() event handler to your <select> box and hide/show news items based on the selected value. Example:

```
$('#sort-news').change(function() {
   var NewsType = $(this).val();
   $('.news-item[data-category!="' + NewsType + '"]').hide();
   $('.news-item[data-category="' + NewsType + '"]').show();
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G7mLj/

If, in addition to hide/showing news items based on the selected category you also want to sort the remaining items by some other attribute, TinySort is great for this. Update your question with those details (and perhaps some additional markup - if you filter by data-category, it's not clear what you would sort on).